# Animation scatter plot ( delete the previous point )

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, scatter-plot, point

I would like to animate a scatter plot that just shows the current point and delete the last point. I already have a code that runs well but I don't know how to delete the previous point.

This is my code:

```
img = plt.imread("/Users/hadis/Desktop/project/5_Data/08_background.png") 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.imshow(img,extent=[0,1170,-780,0]) 

x2 = new_x[:,0]
y2 = new_x[:,1]

scat = ax.scatter(x2,y2,s=10)

def animate(i):
    scat.set_offsets(np.hstack((x2[:i], y2[:i])))
    return scat,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, repeat=False,
                                frames=len(x2) , interval=20, blit= False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Change `(x2[:i], y2[:i])` to `(x2[i], y2[i])`

Comment: `[:i]` takes all points up to the `i`th point, whereas you want only the `i`th point `[i]`